# Linux NAT server with two uplinks

Tags: linux, ip, routing, nat

In linux FC9, setting eth0 has default, ping -I eth1 IP address is working fine. In FC14 tehe same does not work. The above check is done to test the connectivity from that interface so that if the default link connectivity goes down, the default gateway will be changed. Please help me.

Regards,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up IP multihoming.

Do this:

create secondary routing table:

`echo -e "200\tuplink2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

add second default route to this table

`echo "default table uplink2 via GA.TE.WA.Y2" > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1`

create a rule to put traffic source with eth1 ip to uplink2 routing table:

`echo "from IP.AD.DR.ES table uplink2" > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1`

restart networking:

`service network restart`